# Background images on MailChimp templates

Tags: css, background-image, mailchimp

How to use background images on MailChimp templates?

It's my first MailChimp template integration, I can't figure out why my background images are ignored.

Here is the html version: http://www.opi.krown.ch/

The problem is that all my background images are simply ignored, as you see there (even in MailChimp code editor/preview):

[image]

I tried several ways, like:

```
#footer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("bg-traits.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  background-image:url("bg-traits.png");
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I also tried to put this rule inline, and to use a jpg file instead png, but nothing is working.

Normally, *background* and *background-image* attributes should be compatible with MailChimp templates, as described there:

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/?_ga=1.130272975.1389054611.1446716703

I checked the documentation:

https://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/mailchimp-for-designers/html/

It seems I am doing everything well. What's the problem?

Comment: If all your syntax is correct, are you sure that MailChimp can find the file? Does it need an absolute URL?

Comment: @dogwoodtree-dot-net, Indeed it worked with an absolute URL, with images stored on my server. The problem is that I will rather prefer a solution with relative URL's

Answer (score 1):

In HTML emails, all images must be provided with absolute links to a publicly available server.
(See http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/common-html-mistakes)

Which only makes sense - when someone opens your email in their inbox, they are only opening your email, not your directory structure. And your email does not have access to their directory structure (what would be one directory up from their Inbox?).